# iPhone: Get countryCode from location manager or map kit

Tags: ios, iphone, location, mapkit

i want to know the countryCode on the base of current location. is is possible using iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MKPlacemark.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPlacemark_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: countrycode is nsstring type and i want to numeric value for country code

Comment: Which standard is that? I don't know any standards based on numeric value for country codes.

Comment: The one you get is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2  There are not that many countries, you might want to do the conversion yourself then.